# Listener for a Stage minimizing, maximizing, etc

Tags: java, window, javafx-2

I am just starting my second JavaFX projects, and I need to know when a `Stage` is being maximized. In Swing, this is fairly simple and can be accomplished by using a WindowListener/Event. However, after searching through JavaFX's Javadoc, I can't seem to find any way of listening to the state of a `Stage`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To find out if `Stage` minimized you can listen to `iconified` property:

```
stage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
        System.out.println("minimized:" + t1.booleanValue());
    }
});
```

Correspondent `maximized` property is added in the upcoming 8.0 release:

```
stage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
        System.out.println("maximized:" + t1.booleanValue());
    }
});
```

You can download early access build of JDK 8 (which includes FX8) here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html

Comment: Thank you! In your opinion, would it be worth developing my application in JDK 8, and then updating it when it's officially released?

Comment: It depends on your development time. JDK8 is quite near, but users may do not instantly update to a major release.

Comment: but how can you implement those in Controller? in initialize method the stage is still null

Comment: @EvgeniyMishustin: you can wrap your logic into `runLater` call: `Platform.runLater(()-> { System.out.println(label.getScene()); });`

Comment: i have tried all of the options but it's not working.  I am using JDK 10, could that be a problem?

Comment: @kinsleykajiva I've just tried with JDK10 and everything works fine. Please, create a separate question with details to get further help.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me.