# JavaFX - Open window in iconified/minimized mode?

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to open a window in minimized mode using JavaFX? 
Currently this code :

```
 stage.setScene(scene);
 stage.setMinHeight(currentWindowHeight);
 stage.show();
```

opens window in the centre of the screen. Adding `stage.setIconified(true)` results in ugly flashed view of stage appearing for a millisecond and minimized. Can this behavior be optimized so the stage will open in minimized mode without flashing on screen? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the stage invisible or opacity to zero before setIconified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMaxHeight(0);
    stage.setMaxWidth(0);
    stage.setOpacity(0);
    stage.setIconified(true);
```

> For the second half of your question,I would go here: [Listener for a Stage minimizing, maximizing, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659817/listener-for-a-stage-minimizing-maximizing-etc)

Before I setIconified I would save the original window's settings in an object. Maybe bounds object(just guessing here). I would then listen for maximizing and restore the original settings. On minimizing, I would re-Iconify. <- This is just me thowing ideas out. Stackover recomends you start a new question if your original question has been answered and you have new problems.

Comment: but how to re-enable everything back afterwards? or on icon click it will restore ?

Comment: Not sure let me look.

Comment: the problem happens in windows - it never comes back from iconified mode again

Comment: Did you set iconified to false?

Comment: @Sedrik Jefferson the problem is when I close window in iconified mode and open a new one  - the new one stage.getX() and getY() return negative values in Windows. In Mac everything is working so thank you!