# Find the width of a scene after maximize

Tags: javafx-11

For my application I want to have a polygon at the `bottomright` corner of my window.
I added a `Changelistener` to the `Width` and `Height` properties so that when I resize the window manually the polygon moves accordingly.
But when I maximize the window the `listeners` activate but they give the `height` and `width` before the maximizing happens.

After I undo the maximizing the listeners also activate but this time they give the `height` and `width` from when it was actually maximized.

This is my code:

```java
ChangeListener<Number> stageSizeListener=(observable, oldValue, newValue)-> {
    infoPanel.setTranslateX(scene.getWidth()-205);
    infoPanel.setTranslateY(scene.getHeight()-125);
};

stage.widthProperty().addListener(stageSizeListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use maximized property:

```
stage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
        System.out.println("maximized:" + t1.booleanValue());
        if(t1.booleanValue()) {
           infoPanel.setTranslateX(scene.getWidth()-205);
           infoPanel.setTranslateY(scene.getHeight()-125);
       }
    }
});
```

FYI the answer is there:
[Listener for a Stage minimizing, maximizing, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659817/listener-for-a-stage-minimizing-maximizing-etc)